# JQuery Selector for target element

Tags: jquery

I have a bit of JS using JQuery

```
function removeTag() {
    $('{...}').doSomething();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.RemoveTag').click(removeTag);
});
```

Is there anything I can replace {...} with to give me the element that was clicked?

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function removeTag() {
    $(this).doSomething();
}
```